# How can i run vue3 "npm run dev" in docker?

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuxt.js

I want to run vue on node image in docker container. But when i do "docker-compose up --build -d", i can't any log in docker container's log and terminal and server isn't run.

Here is my DockerFile
`

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /var/www/html/app/

COPY package*.json ./

COPY . /app

RUN npm ci && npm cache clean --force

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

EXPOSE 3000 
CMD ["npm" "run" "dev"]
```

`

Here is my docker-compose.yml
`

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"

services:
  vue:
    container_name: vue
    image: node:lts
    working_dir: /var/www/html/app/
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - vue-app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/app
    tty: true
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - vue

networks:
  my-network:
```

`

Here is my template github link: https://github.com/cskhw/nuxt3-quasar-template
If you switch branch to "web", you can see my vue project.

Comment: It's not working because it has no node_module. And by the way it is not meant to use `dev` (development mode) in production.

Comment: Are you sure you want your client to download 10mb files instead of 100-300kb ?

Comment: I want to build dev and test server. Therefore i use dev command. And production's docker file has "npm run build" and "CMD ["node", ".output/server/index.mjs"]. Please give me DockerFile solution.

Answer (score 1):

The single biggest thing causing you immediate trouble is this Compose override:

```yaml
# delete this line
entrypoint: /bin/bash
```

This tries to run an interactive shell instead of your dev server; but since Compose runs background services, this shell exits immediately and you can't interact with it at all.

More generally, you have far too many Compose options, and a couple of them are dangerous (notably, you're replacing `node:lts` with your custom image).  I'd reduce the Compose file to just

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  vue:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes: # (probably delete this too)
      - ./:/var/www/html/app
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

For all of the others, either Compose or your Dockerfile provides reasonable defaults.  As I hint in a comment, I'd also typically delete the `volumes:` block, so that you're using the code built into the image and not replacing it with something else; this does conflict with your desire to simulate a local development environment using an isolated container.

(And correspondingly, I think the *actual* easiest thing to do here is to run `npm run dev` directly on your host system, without Docker; it doesn't seem like what you show here particularly benefits from being isolated in a container.)

Comment: Your solution is perfectly working for me. Thank you for your fast answer!!!!!!!!!